# Is there any method to initialize objects that have an attribute of other object (association) from a query in CloudKit?

Tags: swift, database, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm having a problem fetching data using CKReference of an object that i'm currently fetching.

So in this app i have 2 classes:

1. Student
   Here the attribute Group is a reference to a Group class/CKRecord

```swift
struct Student: Identifiable {
    let id: CKRecord.ID
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let dateOfBirth: Date
    let address: String
    let grade: Int
    let gpa: Double
    let group: Group?
    
    static let kFirstName: String = "firstName"
    static let kLastName: String = "lastName"
    static let kDOB: String = "dateOfBirth"
    static let kAddress: String = "address"
    static let kGrade: String = "grade"
    static let kGPA: String = "gpa"
    static let kGroup: String = "group"
    
    init(record: CKRecord, group: Group) {
        self.id = record.recordID
        self.firstName = record[Student.kFirstName] as? String ?? "N/A"
        self.lastName = record[Student.kLastName] as? String ?? "N/A"
        self.dateOfBirth = record[Student.kDOB] as? Date ?? DateComponents(year: 1800, month: 1, day: 1).date!
        self.address = record[Student.kAddress] as? String ?? "N/A"
        self.grade = record[Student.kGrade] as? Int ?? -1
        self.gpa = record[Student.kGPA] as? Double ?? -0.0
        self.group = group
    }
}
```

2. Group

```swift
struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id: CKRecord.ID
    let name: String
    
    static let kName: String = "name"
    
    init(record: CKRecord) {
        self.id = record.recordID
        self.name = record[Group.kName] as? String ?? "N/A"
    }
}
```

The problem occurred whenever i'm trying to fetch all the students data, but i also want to show to the user (in the UI) the information about the group name.
Here i have implement a CloudKit manager to handle all the request to the database.

```swift
//
//  CloudKitManager.swift
//  CKCRUDTraining
//
//  Created by Steven Wijaya on 15.06.2023.
//

import CloudKit

class CloudKitManager {
    private let container: CKContainer = CKContainer.default()
    
    func fetchStudents(completed: @escaping (Result<[Student], Error>) -> ()) {
        // Create sort descriptor
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: Student.kLastName, ascending: true)
        // Initialize query
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: RecordType.student, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        container.publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { [self] records, error in
            // Check if we get an error
            guard error == nil else {
                completed(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            guard let records = records else { return }
            
            var students: [Student] = []
            // Here we are fetching the data of reference to CKRecord `Group` from student data
            for record in records {
                print("Getting reference")
                print(record)
                guard let groupReference = record[Student.kGroup] as? CKRecord.Reference else { return }
                let groupRecordID = groupReference.recordID
                var group: Group?
                fetchGroup(id: groupRecordID) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let success):
                        group = success
                        print("GROUP FOUND: \(success)")
                        break
                    case .failure(let failure):
                        group = nil
                        print("Group not found: \(failure.localizedDescription)")
                        break
                    }
                }
                print("GETTING HERE")
                let student = record.convertToStudent(group: group ?? Group(name: "N/A"))
                print("STUDENT: \(student)")
                students.append(student)
            }
            completed(.success(students))
        }
    }
    
    func fetchGroup(id: CKRecord.ID, completed: @escaping (Result<Group, Error>) -> ()) {
        print(id)
        container.publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: id) { record, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                completed(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            guard let record = record else { return }
            
            let group = record.convertToGroup()
            print("GROUP: \(group)")
            
            completed(.success(group))
        }
    }
    
    func fetchGroups(completed: @escaping (Result<[Group], Error>) -> ()) {
        // Create sort descriptor
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: Group.kName, ascending: true)
        // Initialize query
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: RecordType.group, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        container.publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
            // Check if we get an error
            guard error == nil else {
                completed(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            guard let records = records else { return }
            
            let group = records.map { $0.convertToGroup() }
            
            completed(.success(group))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried several solution i came up online such as saving the referenced objects in a list then filter it (but i think this is not the optimal solution), then i tried to modified my `CloudKitManager` class to handle the request by looping through all the record and then do another fetch on the CKReference.ID (nested escaping closures with completion handler), but it always return `nil` (because the fetched data from CKReference came back later after the first convenience API finish its work)

Do you guys have any solution or recommendation on how to fetch an object that contains another object in CloudKit?

Comment: When you call fetchGroup, pass in the reference to the student record. When the fetchGroup call finishes, you can update the record and send out a notification to the UI. The other approach is to create a dispatch group and use it to delay the completion of the student search until all the group calls have finished. This will work best on small datasets otherwise the delay might get unreasonable.